# Why curl returns different response from telnet from a web server

Tags: http, curl, telnet

Hello I did run `curl` command and equal `telnet` command but response is different.

I try to get HTTP HEADER response code from a web server.

`curl` returns correct response, page indeed doesn't exist. But `telnet` with equal request return different response.

Please see CURL code:

```
$ curl -vI "https://www.abcanchorage.org/not-exist-page-con2uiu28itact"
* About to connect() to www.abcanchorage.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 185.230.63.96...
* Connected to www.abcanchorage.org (185.230.63.96) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=abcanchorage.org
*   start date: Nov 09 17:32:52 2020 GMT
*   expire date: Feb 07 17:32:52 2021 GMT
*   common name: abcanchorage.org
*   issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
> HEAD /not-exist-page-con2uiu28itact HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: www.abcanchorage.org
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 14:06:25 GMT
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 14:06:25 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< content-language: en
content-language: en
< x-wix-request-id: 1607954785.82658627446080423994
x-wix-request-id: 1607954785.82658627446080423994
< Age: 0
Age: 0
< Server-Timing: cache;desc=miss, varnish;desc=miss, dc;desc=84
Server-Timing: cache;desc=miss, varnish;desc=miss, dc;desc=84
< X-Seen-By: r5KTLwzxoi1C+SXup0UeuQ==,sHU62EDOGnH2FBkJkG/Wx8EeXWsWdHrhlvbxtlynkVg1leqePNkwQ1H/U0dj1nMN,2d58ifebGbosy5xc+FRalthBvkD9LHf+OIny1MrcDwiq6+5o8xu+S2UUMqtKcebjUMQY1HiUPm50af1ZAsGkCw==,2UNV7KOq4oGjA5+PKsX47Gzh5saLoQp8TIRIohc0Wac=,m0j2EEknGIVUW/liY8BLLuvhI/meCohDY7RevwAJ7JU=,w4q8mm9FnmU4emOs6psVXTk8VV0IpMOWw3zRTVWAPzKTzRA6xkSHdTdM1EufzDIPWIHlCalF7YnfvOr2cMPpyw==,8OhaUUQpIrZVCQED4XmuQ40tjCf+ijnQjDvVBuKrqCUYXyC7l2oN0jRBomMsk5tniLmOBCJX9PwPq0FFNfh5cw==
X-Seen-By: r5KTLwzxoi1C+SXup0UeuQ==,sHU62EDOGnH2FBkJkG/Wx8EeXWsWdHrhlvbxtlynkVg1leqePNkwQ1H/U0dj1nMN,2d58ifebGbosy5xc+FRalthBvkD9LHf+OIny1MrcDwiq6+5o8xu+S2UUMqtKcebjUMQY1HiUPm50af1ZAsGkCw==,2UNV7KOq4oGjA5+PKsX47Gzh5saLoQp8TIRIohc0Wac=,m0j2EEknGIVUW/liY8BLLuvhI/meCohDY7RevwAJ7JU=,w4q8mm9FnmU4emOs6psVXTk8VV0IpMOWw3zRTVWAPzKTzRA6xkSHdTdM1EufzDIPWIHlCalF7YnfvOr2cMPpyw==,8OhaUUQpIrZVCQED4XmuQ40tjCf+ijnQjDvVBuKrqCUYXyC7l2oN0jRBomMsk5tniLmOBCJX9PwPq0FFNfh5cw==
< Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

< 
* Connection #0 to host www.abcanchorage.org left intact
```

Please see TELNET code:

```
$ telnet www.abcanchorage.org 80
Trying 35.246.6.109...
Connected to www.abcanchorage.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD /not-exist-page-con2uiu28itact HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: www.abcanchorage.org
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 14:08:50 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
location: https://www.abcanchorage.org/not-exist-page-con2uiu28itact
Age: 1496
Server-Timing: cache;desc=hit, varnish;desc=hit, dc;desc=euw2
X-Seen-By: sHU62EDOGnH2FBkJkG/Wx8EeXWsWdHrhlvbxtlynkVgmNySqidgeEPHXBvm3U9iS,2d58ifebGbosy5xc+FRalhEF/w8i5SZb0AgDKvjhMuBVlHGeDiRYk3btR6xZR3zaGgqFbFMYwiXnFojPwdof6LPb61OjwxlOgfM3AWuO4IQ=,2UNV7KOq4oGjA5+PKsX47LZ7Kls+1whC/C/a0aUIqJE=
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1
X-Wix-Request-Id: 1607954930.2811039255969122439
Server: Pepyaka/1.19.0

^]quit

telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Comment: Some servers return correct/same response for both curl and telnet. But some servers return correct response only for curl and incorrect for telnet.

Comment: Now I see, curl was supplied with HTTPS which has 443 port number when telnet was supplied with port 80 is for HTTP. Thus telnet got HTTP 301 code redirection to same page but on HTTPS protocol.